# Do i need to use PHP in customizer api?

Tags: customization, theme-customizer, rest-api

i understand with the wp rest API i will be able to build Wordpress themes with other languages but will i be able to do the same in customizer api or would i need to use php to give customization options to users?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is written in PHP, so you need to know a bit (at least for basic stuff) of PHP in order to develop themes.

Comment: that wasn't the question

Answer (score 0):

The REST API currently supports a method for updating WordPress custom header options (which are sort of a precursor to the full customizer) which is documented here https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/headers/mine/

There is no direct Customizer API endpoint in the REST API, and no endpoint for manipulating Options (which is where Customizer data is stored) so it doesn't appear that you can manipulate the Customizer via the REST API as of API version 1.1.

Comment: i read somewhere that the customizer api interface is rebuilt using undescore.js